# Working with Unity3D and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2013

how do i get Unity3D for debugging the code, and Visual Studio 2013 which i have now to only script the code. Example: Like Flash Professional for debugging and FlashDevelop for scripting only.

My question is, how do i get the Unity3D link with Visual Studio 2013. I already searching around the internet, and had found that Unity3D only works with VisualStudio 2010.

Comment: This isnt a direct answer to your question, but have you considered trying monodevelop instead. Monodevelop comes packaged with unity and Unity has put more effort into integrating it into the unity work flow. Ive used the debugger a lot for a unity-monodevelop project, you just press debug and it automatically links to the unity editor. I know its not an ideal situation though.

Comment: I posted a question for unity3d community but noone answered yet. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173928/how-to-play-an-alpha-video-in-unity-for-android)

Answer (score 41):

I wrote a blog article on this awhile back on my [blog HERE](http://www.strichnet.com/unity-4-and-visual-studio-2012/) for Visual Studio.

However I will paste it here too:

## How to use Visual Studio 2013

1. Recently Microsoft bought and re-released the popular Unity3D plugin UnityVS. The now renamed Visual Studio Tools for Unity plugin smooths the connection between Unity and Visual Studio and even allows one to perform debugging too! [Download it here.](http://www.strichnet.com/unity-4-and-visual-studio-2012/)
2. In Unity Editor go to Edit->Preferences->External Tools and In External Script Editor choose Browse from the drop down box.
3. Browse to and select C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.
4. The External Script Editor should automatically show your selected editor as Visual Studio 2013.
5. That’s it! It should just work from that point on.

Comment: Be sure to run Unity as Administrator

Answer (score 12):

As an important update, I would like to notice, that former UnityVS (after Microsoft's acquisition of SyntaxTree) is now available for free as a rebranded [Visual Studio 2013 Tools for Unity](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/20b80b8c-659b-45ef-96c1-437828fe7cf2).

The versions for [VS 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7ab11d2a-f413-4ed6-b3de-ff1d05157714) and [VS 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6e536faa-ce73-494a-a746-6a14753015f1) are also available.

Answer (score 5):

The integration of Unity3d and Visual Studio got simpler with latest Unity (version 5) and Visual Studio Tools. This is the current procedure.

To use Visual Studio as editor and debugger with Unity you must:

1. Install the Visual Studio Tools For Unity. For this download the package at http://unityvs.com (careful to get the version for the Visual Studio you are using) and import it (as is standard in Unity for packages) by going into *Assets -> Import Package -> Custom Package* and browse to the tools installation folder and pick the package.
2. Once installed in Unity you will get an additional menu *Visual Studio Tools*, go there and select "generate project files". Visual Studio will already be the default editor for your scripts.
3. This done, if you say put a breakpoint in Visual Studio, click on "Attach to Unity" in Visual Studio, and then run your Unity project, the process will stop at breakpoints in Visual Studio and allow variable inspection etc.

Answer (score 4):

you can use unityvs VS plugin (but I'm not sure about current 2013 support, it's works with vs2012) http://unityvs.com/ - on windows it's works very well, but remote OSX debugging feature is not ready yet

Comment: from http://unityvs.com/news/ - The UnityVS team is proud to release our same day support for Visual Studio 2013. All UnityVS customers can download it from their account.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add to the fine answer given by Pietro Polsinelli, that for me, there was an extra step in his Step 1.  And that is that, after installing Visual Studio Tools For Unity, I had to, in Unity, go to Assets->Import Package->Visual Studio 201X Tools and then click around on the menu bar until "Visual Studio Tools" showed up as an option.  After that, I could Generate Project Files and Open in Visual Studio.

This enabled me to Attach to Unity in Visual Studio and debug.

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions worked for me.  Renaming monodevelop just changed the default program to notepad++, and the next default program after that was simply notepad.

However, there is a known bug with Visual Studio 2013 (not sure if it was present in previous versions, or if it is present in the non-professional version) where if you try to open a C# file in visual studio, where Visual Studio is opened as administrator and Unity isn't, VS crashes.

I had to either run both programs (VS and Unity) as administrator, or not open VS as administrator (as per the solution found here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/597863/cannot-open-visual-studio-files-from-windows-explorer).

Answer (score 0):

With Visual Studio You Can Use UnityVS Plugin But if You Use Monodevelop You Can Go To Run->Attach To Process.. And Connect The Debugger to Unity Editor It Work Perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

To link Unity with Visual Studio, do the following:

Do this on Unity.
Go to file --> preferences --> external tools --> external script editor --> Choose visual studio.

If Visual Studio is not showing, you Re gonna have to browse Visual Studio by hand.

Then you open any script in the Unity Project window and Visual Studio should open the file.

I hope this is helpful.
Note that I am using Unity 2020.2 and Visual Studio 2019